# How to stop OSX from re-opening old documents, views, windows etc

Tags: macos

How do you stop OSX from opening previously viewed files in all apps and prevent it from reopening windows on restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restoring application state when reopening apps can be disabled in the General preferences.

[image]

Disabling Resume when logging out and back in is more difficult. [You'll have to resort to hacks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/29343/3936) like running `defaults write com.apple.loginwindow TALLogoutSavesState -bool false` on login with a LaunchAgent.

Comment: Restore windows...is unchecked but it still opens the windows like MS Word?

Comment: @TheLearner I don't know about Word, but some other cross-platform apps like Chrome still use their own implementation of restoring state and might have a separate preference for disabling it.

Comment: The option is now called "close windows when quitting an application".